# Add a function that can be separately used by every sprite in an array

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I need to move balls by clicking on them, but they need to move individually, also I need to use arrays that have the sprites stored in them. I have searched for the past few hours but couldn't find an answer, it is probably pretty obvious, but I am a little tired.

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

/**
 * ...
 * @author Sam
 */
public class Main extends Sprite 
{
    public var array:Array = new Array();
    public var bal:Sprite = new Sprite();

    public function Main():void 
    {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < 501; i++)
        {
            bal.graphics.beginFill(0x00FFFF);
            bal.graphics.drawCircle(600 * Math.random(), 800*Math.random(), 10);
            bal.graphics.endFill();

            array.push(bal);
            array[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gaweg);
            addChild(bal);
        }
    }

    public function gaweg(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        x += 3;
    }
```

Is the code I am currently using, I am obviously a beginner, 'gaweg' is the function used to move a ball and I call the Sprites 'bal'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem should be solved using OOP, i.e. making a `Ball` object with a `gaweg` function. The Ball should also be responsible for drawing itself.

```
public class Ball extends Sprite
{
    public function Ball()
    {
        graphics.beginFill(0x00FFFF);
        graphics.drawCircle(600 * Math.random(), 800 * Math.random(), 10);
        graphics.endFill();

        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _gaweg);
    }

    private function _gaweg(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        x += 3;
    }
}
```

This way, `Ball` is a standalone object that can draw itself and has its own click handler. From here you can simplify your current code to:

```
public class Main extends Sprite
{
    public var balls:Array = [];

    public function Main()
    {
        for(var i:int = 0; i < 501; i++)
        {
            var ball:Ball = new Ball();
            balls.push(ball);
            addChild(ball);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, but thanks a lot, it worked!
Should have known it myself though.
Have a nice day.